# Azure function SDK Causing Newtonsoft issue

Tags: c#, azure, json.net, azure-functions

We are using azure function SDK   in visual studio 2017  in  .Net Frame work 4.6. We have added nuget packages

> Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared    1.15.1
>   Newtonsoft.Json        12.0.1
>    AzureFunctions.Autofac 3.0.7  (for dependency injection )

when creating  a instance of  Twin we are getting a  the following exception message

> "message": "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json,Version=10.0.0.0, > Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.",

We tried downgrading the package to

> Newtonsoft.Json  10.0.1

Then we are getting the same error by replacing missing Newtonsoft.Json   version   10.0.1 with   Newtonsoft.Json  version   12.0.1  .

this is the  code we are following .

```
    Twin updatetwin = new Twin(); 
    updatetwin.ETag = "*"; 
    var body = await RequestBody(req); 
    var newtwin =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PropertyViewModel>(body);
```

Comment: do you have to use .NET Framework? If you could switch to NET Core and Functions v2, the whole issue about dependencies should go away.

Comment: @silent we have a lot code written in .net frame work  changing it will take a lot of time is there any other way to solve the dll missing issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using

> Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1

with .net framework 4.6 and

> Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.13

You can check required dependencies in nuget package manager-

[image]

Comment: We  cannot downgrade Newtonsoft.Json below 10.0.1 since 
Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared 1.15.1  will  not work below 10.0.1 .  
Is there any we can specify which version of  newtonsoft.json  to use   like as in app.config /web.config?

Comment: You can use  Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions = 1.0.28 as it has dependency on Newtonsoft.Json (= 11.0.2)